# If I have a useState which has a value of 4, how can I use the below function to create the returned HTML 4 times using the value? (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, for-loop

I am trying to create a quiz app which at the end of each round creates a table which contains the players score as well as the score of a set number of random players. Lets say the number of random players has been pre selected and is 4. How do I use the value of 4 from the useState to render the below HTML 4 times? I couldn't get for loop to work, maybe someone else can or has another idea?

```
    function Players () {
      
      return <><tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{teamName}</td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td>{score}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of desired length using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and fill it with the `Players` component and then render the array.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(4);

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: count }, () => (
        <Players />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array constructor to do this.

Code:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(4);

{
   [...Array(number)].map((_, index) => (
    <div className="" key={index}> Whatever needs to be repeatedly </div>
       )
    )
 }
```